# why nodejs pg with redshift returns only one row all the times?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-redshift

I have a strange issue with the npm-pg library which is returning only one row. but I have more rows in the table when I checked the database table. could someone shed some light?

```
import pg from 'pg';
export const sample = async (event, context) => {
pg.defaults.ssl = true;
const client = new pg.Client();
 //console.log(client);
 await client.connect();
  const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM Sampletable ');
 //console.log(res);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(res.rows));
return res;
```

result has:
only one row:`[{"XXXX":"YYYY"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the confusion - I was using different data base which has only one row and always checking on the other db while querying manually. phew!